# Saving unit test results after running tests

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio 2013, running all my Visual Studio unit tests shows the test results, together with callstack, exception information and a stack trace of failing tests. Is there any way of saving the test results, after test execution, such that I can open up previously run tests?

I have read posts that explain that failing test results are kept, in the TestResults folder, while successful tests are deleted. Unfortunately neither failing nor successful test results remain, in my TestResults folder, after running the tests.

I tried creating and using a .runsettings file and setting the  element to false, but this didn't change anything.

Anyone know how to keep the test results, for later inspection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi I have the same problem, the solution for me was use command console.

You need to use VSTest.console.exe located at : **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow**

You should go to that location using visual studio command prompt. After that type: **VSTest.console yourFullProjectPath\YourTestProject\bin\reléase\YourTest.dll /logger:trx**

After completed you can find results in **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\TestResults**

Regards

Comment: While this doesn't allow me to run the unit tests from within Visual Studio, running the tests from the command console will store the results as needed. It appears to be the closest I can get to what I want.

Comment: I don't see a dll file in that folder.

Answer (score 5):

In Visual Studio 2019, the closest I can get to a 'report' using just the GUI and no command lines is to select the tests you want to export (you can use `CTRL+A` to select all) and then using `CTRL+C` to copy.

[image: Just select them all like this]

Afterwards, you can paste to any text editor or Excel spreadsheet, it will look a bit funky like this:

[image: Result after pasting to Excel]

As you can see, the first column has the test name and result. But with a bit of manipulation in Excel then you probably can get some nicer looking result :)

Comment: This will work only if selected test cases. In my case, I have grouped by traits, so `ctrl + A` not worked me, however manually selecting those cases worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 17 you can dump test results by copying the test from Test Explorer:

[image]

Then, paste to some text editor:

[image]

Comment: Fwiw, in VS 2019, I only have `Copy Details`, which gives pretty sparse info on rolled up test success, like `Duration: 0:26:02.626
14 test(s) failed
0 test(s) skipped
22 test(s) passed`. If you have access to 2019, do you still have this option in 2019?

Comment: Just found this after 2 years and a VS upgrade :D and no, there is no option like this in VS 2019

Answer (score -2):

In your test try to insert the following

```
TestContext->AddResultFile( "MyTestFile.txt" );
```

Regards

Comment: Calling TestContext.AddResultFile in the TestInitialize phase, didn't change anything.