# Generate .trx file via code in c#

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, trx

I was able to generate the unit test result(.trx) file with the help of below link :

[Saving unit test results after running tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28235129/saving-unit-test-results-after-running-tests)

Apart from using cmd to generate the .trx file, is there any way to generate the same via code itself.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Below is the my sample code :

```
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo myStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        myStartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        myStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        myStartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        myStartInfo.Verb = "runas";
        myStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow";
        myStartInfo.Arguments = @"/C VSTest.console C:\UnitTestProject1\UnitTestProject1\bin\Debug\UnitTestProject1.dll /logger:trx"; 
        process.StartInfo = myStartInfo;
        process.Start();
```

Please note that cmd needs to be run as admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can run any cmd command using C#. You have to look at the classes in the Process namespace.

Here you have a good document with an example at the end showing different options:

[Process.Start MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I tried to execute the commands mentioned in the link I had shared, using Process. However, I couldn't succeed. Request you to share sample code to generate the required .trx file.

Comment: It's better if you share the code you did to achieve that and we will look why it's wrong.

Comment: Try to run just the VSTest.console and running the C# app as admin to see if it works.