# How do I save test results from Test Explorer in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio

I have an issue with Visual Studio 2017. I generally run a set of tests locally on my own computer using Test Explorer and using Microsoft's own Unit Testing tools in the Visual Studio library. This can take quite sometime. Problem is, if I close visual studio at any point, the results of these tests are lost forever: the pass, the fail, the output, everything.

I need a way to save the results of my tests in case this happens. I'd love it if VS didn't just wipe my test results like this.

I have to run many tests in different windows, using the command prompt to do this is incredibly laborious.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving unit test results after running tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28235129/saving-unit-test-results-after-running-tests)

Comment: Let me check if that works for VS 2017

Comment: That solution is neither pragmatic for my case nor does it actually work.

Comment: I don't have a DLL file in that location

Comment: sorry for getting back so late, I tested and added the solution as an answer, do let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: Copy the test from test explorer and paste to some text file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61404430/3190306

Answer (score 8):

You can use the command line tool [VSTest.Console.exe command-line options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/vstest-console-options?view=vs-2017) and save the output to file using `/Logger:` option.

It can be found under

> (Visual-Studio-Directory)\(Version-Year)\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform

Sample:

```
vstest.console.exe "C:\TestProjectFolder\TestProject.dll" --logger:trx
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure trace logging using a test settings file, documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?branch=release-16.4&view=vs-2019#loggerrunsettings-element).